# Delete duplicated info

Tags: powershell, csv

I've the following CSV

```
USER/PRIMARY_GROUP/OTHER_GROUPS
X/adm/staff 
Y/staff/staff,users
```

I need the following result:

```
USER/PRIMARY_GROUP/OTHER_GROUPS
X/adm/staff 
Y/staff/users
```

So if the group already exists in PRIMARY_GROUP column, it must be removed from OTHER_GROUPS column. In order to do so I have:

```
$Match = Import-Csv $UserReport4 -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($Line in $Match) {
  if ($Line.Primary_Group -match $Line.Secondary_Group) {
    Remove-Item $Line
  } 
}
```

And the only output I get is:

> Remove-Item cannot bind argument to parameter 'path' because it is an empty string

Comment: You may want to read up on what [remove-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) actually does - you're trying to use it for something it doesn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a calculated property where you split the group list, remove the primary group from the resulting list, and join it back to a comma-separated string:

```
Import-Csv $UserReport4 -Delimiter ';' |
    Select-Object USER, PRIMARY_GROUP, @{n='OTHER_GROUPS';e={
        (($_.OTHER_GROUPS -split ',') -ne $_.PRIMARY_GROUP) -join ','
    }}
```